How to have part of Github pages website not following template but using given code?
For my first github page I managed to use a template that fits my needs to present my project (just-the-docs).
The programming language I'm using for the project has a tool that generates the code for a static website to document the classes, functions and so on...
I would like to have part of my github pages website not using the template and using only the generated code.
Is that possible and if so how to do it ?
p.s.: Until now I tried to put the simplest html file in some places on the repo before using github actions hoping that it would be viewable from the github pages website but I had no success.
